# Unable to to self-deactivate plugin using deactivate_plugins()

Tags: plugins, deactivated-plugin

I have these plugin files:

- my-plugin/my-plugin.php
- my-plugin/my-plugin-class.php

In `my-plugin.php` I have the following line:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $my_plugin_object, 'on_activate_my_plugin' ) );
```

In `my-plugin-class.php` I have the following methods:

```
public function on_activate_my_plugin() {
    if ( // Some validation failed ) {
        wp_mail( 'test@test.com' , 'test', 'test' );

        deactivate_plugins( 'my-plugin/my-plugin.php' );
        add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'my_plugin_activation_failed' ) );
    }
}

public function my_plugin_activation_failed() {
    ?><div class="notice notice-error"><p>The <strong>My Plugin</strong> could not be activated because of something.</p><p>Do the thing and activate the plugin.</p></div><?php
}
```

I get the e-mail but nothing else happens.
The plugin does not self-deactivate.
I am also not getting the admin notice.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Activation hook is fired while the plugin is being activated, at best it is a dangerous assumption to make that at that point it is already active, and if it is not active, obviously you can not deactivate it.

If you are looking for a way to fail the activation, the best way is probably to `die()`